# Combine time series data as input for CatBoost/XGboost

Tags: pandas, time-series, xgboost, catboost

I have time series data in a pandas dataframe. This is not only one time series data but different ones depending on the ID. I want to now train a CatBoost model with a rolling window approach. Therefore, I need to combine the rolling window from rows into columns, meaning for each column I get X times the amount of columns where X is the rolling windows size.

Therefore, I wanted to ask how do I best approach this? How do I best combine the rows into columns based on the ID?

Thanks in advance!